# How to Select Multiple data from drop down in django form(Field has M2M relation in database)?

Tags: python, django

I have one many to many field in my model.py

here in my form the developer field i want to select multiple data and update that in table. some one plese help to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the *wrong* widget for your field. The default form field for a `ManyToManyField` is a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` which has `SelectMultiple` as its default widget, whereas you are using `Select` as the widget.

The widgets you can use are either `SelectMultiple` or  `CheckboxSelectMultiple` (You can refer the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/) for all the widgets that are available):

```py
class jiraReg(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = jira
        fields = ['Jira_ID', 'Jira_Story', 'Short_Description', 'Story_Points', 'Sprint','DX4C_Object','Developer','Sandbox']
        widgets = {
            ...
            # Use SelectMultiple below
            'Developer':forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'id':'Developer'}),
            '...
            }
```

Also you write `fm.save.m2m()` in your view which doesn't make much sense. Simply remove that line.

---

> **Note**: You break various naming conventions in Python in your code. variables / functions are supposed to be named in `snake_case`,
> classes in `PascalCase`. Please have a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide
> for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)